# Implementing GraphQL stitch with RabbitMQ in NestJS

Tags: graphql, rabbitmq, nestjs, stitch

I'm working on a NestJS task where I must use GraphQL stitching with RabbitMQ. I actually have explored various options, however am having trouble finding clean and exact commands on a way to obtain this integration.
problem:

I want to set up a microservices architecture using GraphQL stitching, and I've chosen RabbitMQ as the message broker. However, I'm not sure about the specific steps and configurations needed to make GraphQL stitch work with RabbitMQ in NestJS.

How can I handle schema stitching in a microservice architecture using RabbitMQ for communication between services?